# Custom Loss Function Equation

Tags: tensorflow, loss-function, mathematics, research

I am trying to reproduce a research paper, where it is a classification problem, and they have introduced a custom loss function that I am unable to understand.
[image]

Now I think I have to implement the equation (8) or equation (7) and I am using Tensorflow framework, but I am not able to understand the equation (8) as we have to input both **Actual** and **Predicted** Features in custom loss, but there answer is `klog(lambda+1)`

Similarly in equation 7, they are only using pi and pj which are actuall output i guess, but not yi and yj.

I am using Tensorflow 2 framework. Can someone help me explain these equations and some help in implementation.

I know it is not a reproducable example, but I need some direction to make it reproducable.

### Edit

Link for paper:
https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9148944

Comment: could you please cite the paper

Comment: Sure. Here is it https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9148944